# English 16.04 server with German keyboard: locale errors

Tags: keyboard, locale

I've installed my server in English but use a German keyboard and it basically works. BUT I frequently (e.g. apt-get update) get warnings and I would like to get rid of those:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Another issue I have is with virsh:

```
$ virsh dumpxml template
setlocale: No such file or directory
```

The setlocale command is provided by `gnulib` and I could install that. BUT:

```
0 upgraded, 89 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 206 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Seriously, 200+MB to configure a keyboard? I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: It's not the _command_ setlocale that virsh is missing, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the first problem by generating the German locale:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```